Python: Archerfish Algorithm - Array assignment and indexing issues in optimization algorithm implementation
import numpy as np

def equation_3(Xk_t, omega, theta, delta):
    d = len(Xk_t)  # Issue occurs here
    random_position = np.random.randint(0, d)
    new_position = np.zeros(d)
    new_position[random_position] = omega * np.sin(2 * theta)
    return Xk_t + new_position + delta

def equation_5(Xi_t, omega, theta, delta):
    d = len(Xi_t)  # Issue occurs here
    random_positions = np.random.choice(range(d), 2, replace=False)
    new_position = np.zeros(d)
    new_position[random_positions] = omega * np.sin(2 * theta)
    return Xi_t + new_position + delta

def AHO(d, domains, f, theta, omega, N, Itermax, alpha, xmin, xmax):
    X = np.zeros((N, Itermax))
    for t in range(1, Itermax):
        for i in range(N):
            theta_0 = equation_6(alpha)
            if 0 < abs(theta_0) < theta or np.pi - theta < abs(theta_0) < np.pi:
                Xk_t = np.random.uniform(xmin, xmax, size=d)
                delta = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=d)
                X[i, t] = equation_3(Xk_t, omega, theta, delta)
                # Other parts of the AHO function...

This code implements key components of the Archerfish Algorithm, which mimics the hunting behavior of archerfish in nature. However, I'm encountering issues related to array assignment and indexing:

In equation_3, I'm trying to compute the length of Xk_t to determine the dimensionality of the problem. However, I'm getting a TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len() error. How can I fix this?

Similarly, in equation_5, I'm attempting to compute the length of Xi_t, but this also leads to a TypeError. How can I correctly compute the length of the array?


Additionally, in the AHO function, I'm facing issues with array assignment and indexing, particularly in the condition where equation_3 is called. How can I resolve these issues and ensure proper array manipulation in my implementation of the Archerfish Algorithm?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
I attempted to debug the code by inspecting each equation function  to identify any potential errors. Additionally, I reviewed the numpy documentation and relevant resources to ensure I was using array operations and indexing correctly.
but i encountered multiple errors related to array assignment and indexing. These errors manifested as "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" and "TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()", indicating issues with how arrays are being manipulated and accessed within the code.

Xk_t is not an array.  It is an array element.

stop debugger at Xk_t = np.random.uniform(xmin, xmax, size=d) with condition d==1

Even if Xk_t is an array (with more than one element), equation3 looks like it will return an array of the same size.  But with X[i, t]= you are trying to assign that to a single array element.  To get better debugging help you need to provide more information, such as the full error message(s), and if possible a [mcve] (or at least type and shape info on important variables).
